# How to present the retrieved data on a sencha pie chart

Tags: extjs, pie-chart, sencha-charts

I have been searching every where for someone to help me out because it has not been possible for me to present the data sent to my Sencha pie chart from the JSON data store I created for this purpose.

I am displaying the below result from a printed form of my variable array containing the following set of values:

```
Array ([0] => Array ( [0] => 19 [nombre] => 19 [1] => Chargé de mission [type] => Charge de mission )[1] => Array ( [0] => 204 [nombre] => 204 [1] => Pré-adhérent [type] => Pre-adherent )[2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [nombre] => 1 [1] => Administrateur [type] => Administrateur )[3] => Array ( [0] => 25 [nombre] => 25 [1] => Auto-entrepreneur [type] => Auto-entrepreneur )[4] => Array ( [0] => 1157 [nombre] => 1157 [1] => Adhérent [type] => Adherent )[5] => Array ( [0] => 429 [nombre] => 429 [1] => Salarié [type] => Salarie ))
```

Meanwhile to send it to my Sencha pie I use the JSON encoded below:

```
{"success":true,"total":"0","data":[{"0":"19","nombre":"19","1":null,"type":"Charge de mission"},{"0":"204","nombre":"204","1":null,"type":"Pre-adherent"},{"0":"1","nombre":"1","1":"Administrateur","type":"Administrateur"},{"0":"25","nombre":"25","1":"Auto-entrepreneur","type":"Auto-entrepreneur"},{"0":"1157","nombre":"1157","1":null,"type":"Adherent"},{"0":"429","nombre":"429","1":null,"type":"Salarie"}]}
```

I created my JSON store and pie chart as follows:

```
var userStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'rapport/chartTypeProfils.php',
    fields: [{name:'nombre', type:'int'},'type'],
    root: 'data'
    //totalProperty:'total'
});

userPie = Ext.extend( Ext.ux.Portlet,{
    constructor: function(config) {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            //width: 400,
            height: 300,
            title: 'Utilisateur',
            tools: tools,
            //renderTo: 'user',
            items: {
                itemId: 'userStore',
                store: userStore,
                xtype: 'piechart',
                dataField: 'nombre',
                categoryField: 'type',
                //extra styles get applied to the chart defaults
                extraStyle: {
                    legend: {
                        display: 'left',
                        padding: 5,
                        font: {
                           family: 'Tahoma',
                           size: 13
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        userPie.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

This doesn't display the pie chart however.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the ExtJS framework are you using? I can't find any documentation on the `root` property of the `JsonStore`, or the `dataField` and `categoryField`s of the pie chart series which makes me think you're talking about one of Sencha's other products (GXT possibly?)

With that said, I thought I'd knock up a pie chart using the data you provided and the latest ExtJS Framework available on JSFiddle (4.1). The example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/fgX74/ (the code to that example is at the bottom of this post).

Using your code as a starting point, here's what I changed to get it working:

- The `root` property of the JsonStore doesn't exist. It's certainly not documentated so, I changed the data coming in to suit. The data fed in is now just an array of objects (the url you provided would have to be changed to return the data in the same format).
- I've got rid of the portlet and replaced with an actual chart. I don't have access to the `Ext.ux.Portlet` object in order to extend it.
- `dataField` has been replaced with `angleField` and `categoryField` has been replaced with `label` which allows you to define what's displayed in the actual label.

Finally, here's the actual example code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){    
    var userStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        data: [{"0":"19","nombre":"19","1":null,"type":"Charge de mission"},{"0":"204","nombre":"204","1":null,"type":"Pre-adherent"},{"0":"1","nombre":"1","1":"Administrateur","type":"Administrateur"},{"0":"25","nombre":"25","1":"Auto-entrepreneur","type":"Auto-entrepreneur"},{"0":"1157","nombre":"1157","1":null,"type":"Adherent"},{"0":"429","nombre":"429","1":null,"type":"Salarie"}],
        fields: [{name:'nombre', type:'int'},'type'],
        root: 'data'
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        height: 350,
        animate: true,
        store: userStore,
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            angleField: 'nombre',
            showInLegend: true,
            label: {
                field: 'type',
                display: 'rotate',
                contrast: true,
                font: '18px Arial'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```